# The definition of space

Tags: geometry

Space has a lot of different meanings. In geometry, I come across this word very often. What does 'space' refer to in geometry  ?

Comment: Context would help here. What kind of space do you mean exactly?

Comment: Are there different types of spaces in geometry?  Are they - flat (eculedian) space, spherical spac, curved and non-curved space?  I am confused between all these words.  Do all these spaces exist in real life ?

Comment: I would first like to know what exactly a space is in the context of geometry, and then please tell me how many types of spaces there are.

Comment: Oh, there are many different kinds of spaces. I don't think there's a set number of them.

Comment: Why do you think that that there is not a set number of them ?

Comment: There are: vector spaces, topological spaces, metric spaces, affine spaces, function spaces, and other kinds of spaces. Defining "space" is a bit like defining a "number" -- mostly useless as you either get a definition not general enough or too general. You can always create a new notion and call it Sunny's space. The general idea is that a space is the set that our "points" are elements of.

Comment: @Zeno Rogue : And what is Eucledian space and non Eucledian space ?

Comment: Euclidean space is a space that satisfies the axioms of Euclid. Non-Euclidean space is a space that does not -- usually this has an even more precise meaning of a space that satisfies all axioms of Euclid except the fifth one, but people in general can mean very different things when they say "non-Euclidean".

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I have this question -- Does this space (for example- flat space) in geometry refer to the actual space we are living in this universe, especially on earth?

Comment: Euclidean space is a very simple mathematical model. Before the invention of non-Euclidean geometry people believed that this model describes our space accurately (even if it did not describe the surface of Earth, it did describe the three-dimensional Universe), but as hyperbolic and Riemannian geometry have been created some people have started to think that other possibilities could in fact be true, and now from General Relativity Theory we know that the real world is much more complex than Euclidean geometry says.

Comment: But it is still useful to use Euclidean geometry in small scales. Riemannian or Minkowski geometry is way too complex for most "real life" situations, and the extra precision is not worth the effort.

Comment: Thanks a lot, my friend. Now all my doubts are clear thanks to you. I wish I could hug you.  I have a question - Is spherical and hyperbolic geometry a form of plain geometry?  And are 3D structures like cube, cuboid, cylinder and cone..etc possible in those types of geometries ? Are 3D structures like cube, cuboid etc only found in 3D Eucledian geometry?

Comment: You can have hyperbolic ($\mathbb{H}^d$), Euclidean ($\mathbb{R}^d$), and spherical ($\mathbb{S}^d$) geometry in any number of dimensions $d$. Of course you need at least 3 dimensions to speak of cubes. Platonic solids exists in other geometries, but they will act a bit differently, e.g. a hyperbolic cube will have angles smaller than 90 degrees, so it will not tesselate $\mathbb{H}^3$ as Euclidean cubes tesselate $\mathbb{R}^d$ (but it can tesselate in other way). Try Hyperbolic VR to see what $\mathbb{H}^3$ looks like, or our HyperRogue for a detailed study of life in $\mathbb{H}^2$.

Comment: I cannot thank you enough! Thanks for being out there and helping me. I was in all these confusions for the last week. Things are clear now.

Comment: @Zeno Rogue, what could be the possible 4th or 5th dimension in any geometry be it hyperbolic or Spherical or the geometry other than length, width and height ?

Comment: Sunny, can you edit the question with enough detail so that @ZenoRogue can actually write an answer to it? I feel there is some value in the discussion thread here, but the question as it stands has little value, and probably no reasonably scoped answers.