# In some cases, the `space` means just an arbitrary set that may not have an geometric meaning, is this understanding right?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, measure-theory

people use `space` everywhere, for instance, euclidean space, topological spaces, and this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2982479/678038) is discussing the topic without a specific field.

consider this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3308156/678038)

> We need to know how to measure the “size” or “volume” of subsets of a
>   `space` X before we can integrate functions f : X → R or f : X → C.

it seems that the `space` here means just an arbitrary set that may not have an geometric meaning, is this understanding right?

Comment: A space usually comes equipped with some additional structure. Indeed, this will be the case in this scenario too. This first sentence only serves as sort of motivation, but actual integration will only take place on a measure space $(X,\mathfrak{A},\mu)$.

Comment: Usually, "space" has *some* roots in geometry, though the reality is that the space may be quite divorced from its geometric roots (e.g. topological spaces). To be fair, this describes about 50% of all mathematics.

Comment: People use “space” for sets and other things about which they think with a geometric intuition. For example, “orbit spaces” in the theory of group actions or “vector spaces” in general linear algebra – in their most general and abstract terms, these are no geometric objects, yet we do have some geometric intuition coming from prototypical examples. Most of time, these spaces are sets endowed with some kind of additional structure, but they may also only appear in some context with geometric intuition without carrying any special structures themselves.

Comment: A [sample space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sample_space) is an example of a "space" with no geometric structure.